# Impossible Covering Properties for Sets of Reals

Tags: general-topology

I've been reading more about [selection principles (covering properties)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_principle) recently. Below is terminology.

Adapting what B. Tsaban said in [this article](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~tsaban/Pdf/PublishedBackUp/FuturespmBU.pdf), we consider spaces $X$ which are (homeomorphic to) sets of reals. This will help to filter out problems arising from topologically-pathological examples.

Let $A$ and $B$ be collections of covers of $X$.

- $S_1(A, B)$ means for each sequence $\{\mathcal{U}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of members of $A$, there are members $U_n \in \mathcal{U}_n$ such that $\{U_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \in B$.

In other words, this builds a new cover for $X$ by picking a single element from each $\mathcal{U}_n$.

Some covers come into play:

- $\mathcal{U}$ is an $\omega$-cover of $X$ if each finite subset of $X$ is contained in some $U \in \mathcal{U}$.
- $\mathcal{U}$ is a $\gamma$-cover of $X$ if $\mathcal{U}$ is infinite and each $x \in X$ belongs to all but finitely many $U \in \mathcal{U}$.

By cover, we mean proper covers of $X$ (where $X$ is not a cover of itself).

- $O$ is the collection of all open covers of $X$,
- $\Gamma$ is the collection of all $\gamma$-covers of $X$,
- $\Omega$ is the collection of all $\omega$-covers of $X$.

We can also assume that all the covers in these collections are countable.

In [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9509211v1.pdf) by W. Just, A.W. Miller, M. Scheepers, and P.J. Szeptycki, it is mentioned that a couple selection principles of this form cannot hold for certain $X$.

> $S_1(O, \Gamma)$ and $S_1(O, \Omega)$ are impossible for non-trivial $X$.

I'm having a hard time seeing why these two selection principles are impossible for non-trivial $X$. Is there a property that prevents these two selection principles from happening since we are considering spaces $X$ which are (homeomorphic to) sets of reals?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why the vague reference "an article by M. Scheepers"? You mean to say you don't know the title of the article, or where it was published?

Comment: By "Let $X$ be the set of reals" do you mean "Let $X=\mathbb R$" or do you mean "Let $X\subseteq\mathbb R$"? If the latter, the meaning would be clearer if you changed the definite article to the indefinite article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very difficult to notice the following.

> **Observation 1.** If $A$ and $B$ are collections of covers of $X$ and there is a cover $\mathcal U\in A$ such that no countable subcover of $\mathcal U$ is in $B$, then $S_1(A,B)$ is false.

*Proof.* Simply take $\mathcal U_n=\mathcal U$. If $X$ is $S_1(A,B)$ then there is $\{U_n; n\in\mathbb N\}\subseteq \mathcal U$ which belongs to $B$. I.e., we have a countable subcover of $\mathcal U$ which belongs to $B$. $\square$

---

We may also notice that if $\mathcal U$ has an $\omega$-subcover then $\mathcal U$ itself is an $\omega$-cover.

It is not clearly stated what it means that $X$ is non-trivial, but we can see that:

> **Observation 2.** If $X$ has an open cover which is not $\omega$-cover, then $X$ does not have property $S_1(\mathcal O,\Omega)$.

Now the only question is whether for non-trivial $X$ there is an open cover which is not $\omega$-cover. Since you mentioned in the question that you are interested only in subspaces of $\mathbb R$ (and their subspaces), this should be sufficient.

> **Observation 3.** If $X$ is a [regular Hausdorff space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_space) which has at least two points, then there is an open cover of $X$ which is not $\omega$-cover.

*Proof.* Simply take some two points $a\ne b$. Then we have an open set $V$ such that $a\in V$ and $b\notin V$.

From regularity we also have another open set $U$ such that $a\in U$ and $\overline U\subseteq V$.

Then ve have $\mathcal U=\{V, X\setminus \overline U\}$ is an open cover of $X$. But there is no set in $\mathcal U$ which contains both $a$ and $b$. $\square$

---

Since every $\gamma$-cover is also $\omega$-cover, we have $S_1(\mathcal O,\Gamma) \Rightarrow S_1(\mathcal O,\Omega)$. So if $S_1(\mathcal O,\Omega)$ is impossible, so is $S_1(\mathcal O,\Gamma)$.